# Beacon UUID Description

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I'm working on an iOS app which ranges beacons within a region.  I have a CLLocationManager delegate which periodically gets the information from all of the beacons within the region.  I have a for loop which loops through all the found beacons and prints the data to the console.

```
for i in 0..<knownBeacons.count{
    var uuid = knownBeacons[i].proximityUUID.description
    println(uuid)
}
```

However, when I print the UUID description of each beacon, it adds additional information.  For example, the print statement returns:

```
<__NSConcreteUUID 0x1700351e0> B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D
```

What I'm really looking for is just the last part 'B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D' and would like to remove everything in the < > brackets.  Can someone tell me how to do this?  Or if I shouldn't be using the UUID.description property and should be using something else.  Thanks.

**Update: For the sake of clarity, I have included the full ViewController class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), identifier: "Estimotes")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self;
        if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse){
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!){
        let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
        if(knownBeacons.count > 3) {           
            for i in 0..<3{
                var uuid = knownBeacons[i].proximityUUID
                var major = knownBeacons[i].major
                var minor = knownBeacons[i].minor
                var proximity = knownBeacons[i].proximity.rawValue
                var rssi = knownBeacons[i].rssi
                var accuracy = knownBeacons[i].accuracy.description
                println(uuid)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var uuid = knownBeacons[i].proximityUUID!.UUIDString
```

Comment: Unfortunately... I tried that.  I get the following error in XCode: `'NSUUID!' does not have a member named 'UUIDString'`

Comment: Why does it say NSUUID!, is it an optional that needs to be unwrapped? for example `let thing = NSUUID()` `let that = thing.UUIDString` `println(that)` works for me. How are you creating the knownBeacons array?

Comment: I have updated the original question to clarify how I'm creating the knownBeacons array.

Comment: Yes, you need to unwrap the NSUUID that proximityUUID provides.  Updated my answer.